# not able to find windows service template in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2019

I want to developed windows service using visual studio 2019 using c# language .but when I select >> new project >> search I couldn't find windows service template . what I do next. how i create windows services using visual studio 2019. can we used console application as windows services??

Comment: Try to use visual studio install to download the dependencies of the service service.

Comment: What workloads did you choose when installing VS? The template won't be installed if you just picked e.g. web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to create a window service.

1. Select Window Service. As shown below.

   [image]
2. Add the installer. Double-click service1.cs and then click the right mouse button in the displayed interface to add the installer

   [image]
3. Configure the properties of the installer. Configure the properties of serviceProcessInstaller and serviceInstaller.

   [image]

   [image]
4. Write the code of the service. OnStart: execute when the service starts, OnStop: execute when the service stops. Write logs when starting and stopping execution.

   ```
    string filePath = "C:\\temp\\1.txt";
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
        writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" + ":service start"));
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
        writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" + ":service close"));
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
   ```
5. Generate the .exe file. Because the direct opening of MyService.exe will report an error and the service cannot be started. It requires installutil to install

   [image]